# Error message not showing if the user enters incorrect information

Tags: php, mysqli, authentication

I am trying to display the error at the end if the use doesn't enter the correct combination of their log in. However, the error message is not showing when I enter the wrong password or email. Any suggestions

```
 <?php
 include ("connect.php");

if (isset($_POST["user_login"]) && (isset($_POST["user_pass"]))){
    // formatting field via reg replace to ensure email and password only conisists of letters and numbers preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','', 
    $login_user = $_POST["user_login"];
    $login_password = $_POST["user_pass"];


    // password is encryted in DB (MD5) therefore user inputted password will not match encryted password in DB - we have to assign new var
    $decrypted_password = md5($login_password);

// Query which finds user (if valid) from DB - Achieving authentication via username and password       

$user_query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$login_user' AND password = '$decrypted_password' AND closed = 'no' LIMIT 1"); 

    $check_user = mysqli_num_rows($user_query); // checking to see if there is infact a user which those credentials in the DB
        if ($check_user==1){

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($user_query)){
                $id = $row['user_id'];
                $user_type = $row['account'];
            }
            $_SESSION["user_login"] = $login_user;
            // check the user type and redirect according to it
            if($user_type == "Student"){
             $student_page = "profile_student.php";
             header( "Location:{$student_page}" );

           } elseif ($user_type == "Landlord"){
              $landlord_page = "landlord_profile.php";
              header( "Location:{$landlord_page}" );

           } elseif ($user_type == "Administrator"){
               $admin_page = "admin_profile.php";
               header( "Location:{$admin_page}" );

           }else {
               $refresh_page = "sign_up.php";
               header( "Location:{$refresh_page}" ); // refresh page

            echo "You have entered an incorrect email or password. Please try again.";

           }
           }
}

    ?>
```

Comment: Proper indenting should make clear what the problem is. Also note that you are not likely to see anything that comes after a redirect to another page.

Comment: @jeroen I have tried to just display the error message however that doesnt work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you redirect user if input data is wrong and only after that you try to echo message, thats not how that works. read about headers in [php_manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php). probably the best way here, is to store error message in session and after redirect check if session error message exists

```
else {
           $refresh_page = "sign_up.php";
            $_SESSION['error'] = "your error message"
           header( "Location:{$refresh_page}" ); // refresh page
       }
```

in  sign_up.php file check if error message exists in session

```
if(isset($_SESSION["error"])){
     echo $_SESSION["error"];
      unset($_SESSION["error"]);
  }
```

maybe you should correct this code a little bit))
use unset cause' after you show the message it should be removed from session, in other case if you fail for example 5 times, it will show 5 messages)) also make sure that session is started `session_start()` hope it helps:)

Answer (score 0):

You only display the error when `$user_type` doesn't match any of your expected types.

You need a second `else` after your `if ($check_user==1){` block to handle the case where a user with that email or password doesn't exist.